# Can anyone tell me how to get the geo-coordinates of lanes also?

Tags: xml, openstreetmap, sumo

I have a file `osm.net.xml`, which is taken from a real map. The file includes shape (X/Y coordinates) for both the edges and lanes. I ran below command to convert/create the files to include geo-coordinates:

`netconvert --sumo-net-file osm.net.xml --plain-output-prefix plain --proj.plain-geo`

The input file is as follows (it includes x/y coordinates for both the `edges` and `lanes`):

[image]

I get the output files as:

[image]

I don't see any output-file containing the geo-coordinates for lanes. In the `plain.edg.xml`, there is only shape information for the edges but not for the lanes:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to get the geo-coordinates of `lane`s also???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently not possible to do this. You could only try to parse the network with a python script and do the geo conversion yourself, see the examples here: https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Tools/Sumolib.html#import_a_network_and_retrieve_nodes_and_edges
It will probably boil down to something like:

```
import sumolib
net = sumolib.net.readNet('myNet.net.xml')
laneShape = net.getLane('myLaneID').getShape()
for x, y in laneShape:
    lon, lat = net.convertXY2LonLat(x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks @Micheal . It is helpful. This is great. Does this kind of a conversion take a lot of time. I am asking whether is it a good/efficient way to convert the X/Y to lon/lat in a running python application server. Or is it better to convert the x/y to lon/lat all at once before the provisioning of the application?

Comment: I am not sure but it should not be too slow and I would just give it a try. You can still optimize later.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this to read the whole `XML` file. Converted each of the x,y pair values to longitudes, latitudes as follows:

```
# Read the XML file 
tree = et.parse(PATH_TO_XML_FILE) 
file = tree.getroot() 

geoCoordinatesString = "" 

# Iterate edge nodes in the file 
for edge in file.iter('edge'): 

    # Iterate lanes of the current edge-node 
    for lane in edge.iter('lane'): 
        laneID = lane.get("id") 
        laneShape = lane.get("shape") 
        laneCoordinates = laneShape.split() 
        geoCoordinatesString = "" 

        # Iterate each coordinate in the shape of lane 
        for coordinate in laneCoordinates: 
            geoCoordinates = np.array(coordinate.split(",")) 
            geoCoordinates = geoCoordinates.astype(float) 
            geoCoordinateLon, geoCoordinateLat = net.convertXY2LonLat(geoCoordinates[0],geoCoordinates[1]) 
            geoCoordinatesString = "{:}{:},{:} ".format( 
                geoCoordinatesString, str(geoCoordinateLon), str(geoCoordinateLat) 
            ) 

        # Display each lane's shape geo-coordinates 
        geoCoordinatesString = geoCoordinatesString.strip() 
        print ("- {:}".format(geoCoordinatesString))
```

This output allowed me to store the lane information associated with the lane-ID.